# elasticsearch start error how to resolve this?

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-2.0

i install elasticsearch in centos6.X....(rpm)
but service elasticsearch start command occur error

how to resolve this problem

my java version 1.7.0
my elasticsearch version 2.3.3

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EBKpK.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have permissions issue to /var/lib/elasticsearch folder. Elasticsearch can't write to this folder. You need to recheck under which user works elasticsearch:

```
ps aux | grep elasticsearch
```

and permissions for him:

```
ls -lah /var/lib/elasticsearch
```